# ssh session (from ubuntu to centos) prompt delayed after a while

Tags: bash, ssh

I do a lot of work on a centos (7.2) machine into which i ssh from an ubuntu (14.04) machine.

Everything works fine, almost. But after a while on the remote, usually a couple of minutes, I have to wait for the next prompt (e.g., after just pressing enter) for a couple of seconds. This is really annoying.

Logging out and back in fixes this temporarily, but it happens again after a couple of minutes. I'm not talking about the password prompt upon login or so, that part's fine. It's the regular prompt after being logged in for a while that becomes slow.

Any idea where to look for a solution?

edit:

it also happens logging in from other boxes, but seems to be specific to my user account.

ssh -v shows no additional output when the shell hangs (so after login there's nothing new until logout). here's the last couple of lines from ssh -v:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to X.X.X.X ([X.X.X.X]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to X.X.X.X closed.
Transferred: sent 11888, received 26136 bytes, in 329.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 36.1, received 79.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

htop shows "-bash" to use 100%cpu while i'm waiting for the new prompt.

Comment: it might be useful to out put ssh -v the next time you connect

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what may cause this but in my opinion it looks like a normal connection delay, this can be tweaked by modifying the way you connect to centos.

- Edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config : `Compression yes` to use compression, and `service ssh restart` on server side to disable dns lookup.
- Force IPV4 or IPV6 `ssh -4 user@host` or `ssh -6 user@host`

(Also changing the authentication method can help)

Comment: thanks for the pointers. i don't think it's a server-side issue, though. it only happens when i login from this particular machine, not from somewhere else. (i'll edit the question accordingly)

Comment: by now it also happens form other machines, but apparently only for my user account. compression does not change anything, neither does ipv4. also, i'm pretty sure this is not normal.